# Using Kendo Grid with Breeze and Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, breeze

I'm trying to add a KendoUI grid to my SPA, I'm using the Hot Towel template.  It just show as a line and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've followed the example here:
http://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html

```
    <div data-bind="kendoGrid: items" />
```

Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/Togas/NfK6W

**EDIT**: removed the durandal tag since that doesn't appear to be part of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call ko.applyBindings, viewModel.items is empty, so it uses that to draw the grid...meaning it has no columns and no rows. So you get a line if you haven't defined anything in your binding options. Then when your ajax call completes it fails to redraw.

Define your grid with columns and wrap breeze entities in a rowViewModel with defined columns.

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: items, groupable: true, sortable: true, columns: [ {field: 'Description',width: 90,title: 'Description'}] }"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dcgVA/2/

Comment: Also your fiddle has two kendoGrids, one outside the view being bound so that one wont ever show anything. I figured it was a typo.

Comment: Sorry, just saw this.  Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Updated wrong link.
HotTowel is based on [DurandalJS](http://durandaljs.com/). Did you see http://durandaljs.com/documentation/KendoUI/ and follow the instruction?

Comment: That link takes me to a page with a search box but no results.
Other kendoui controls work with my example, I updated my jsFiddle to include a kendoui.

Comment: Updated the answer with the correct link. As you indicated in your question that you're using Hot Towel, the issue might be with Durandal.

Comment: I'm using the knockout-kendo bindings, the link above says NOT to use those instructions when using knockout-kendo.  Also, the jsFiddle shows the same result and it's not using durandal.

Comment: Your correct. Based on the Durandal tag I was getting the impression that this was Durandal related, which seems to be not the case.